# Tkinter: Using the existence of a TopLevel window as a condition

Tags: python, tkinter

first of all, I know that there is already a question answering this but the way to implement it in the answer isn't clear and I couldn't get it to work.

I want to check whether "top" exists but the way I do it below returns a name error

```py
def createTop():
    top = tk.Toplevel()
    top.title(string="Admin Access")
    top.geometry(newGeometry="300x90")
    top.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    top.lift(aboveThis=root)
    top.update_idletasks()


def TopExists():
    test = print(tk.Toplevel.winfo_exists(top))
    if test == 1:
        print('Exists')
    else:
        print("Does not exist.")
```

I'd appreciate any help on what's the proper way of doing this.

Comment: `top` is a local variable within `createTop()`.  The *variable* doesn't exist anywhere else in your program, regardless of whether or not the window still exists.

Comment: ***"the answer isn't clear and I couldn't get it to work."**: [Edit] your question, show the link to the answer and explain where you get stuck. This should read: `test = print(top.winfo_exists())`

Answer (score 0):

If your Toplevel() window is out of scope, but you know it's `title()`, then you could iterate through the children of your root window and look for an instance of `'!toplevel'` with that name:

```
for widget in rootWindow.winfo_children(): #winfo_children creates a list of every widget object under rootWindow
if '!toplevel' in str(widget):
    if widget.title() == 'Window title you are looking for':
        #Insert conditional code here
```

I use this for making sure if a user already has a certain subwindow open, he can't open a duplicate which might produce a bug.